# In XSD, either any or both elements should be present

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to write an XSD where either any of the EM or RUID should be present, or both can be present. But with the below XSD, I'm getting the following error:

> **Error: Multiple elements with name 'RUID', with different types, appear in the model group.**

```
<xs:element name="ADCNT">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">

      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="EM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="RUID" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>

      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="RUID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="username" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>

    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Either one element or both elements in XSD

This XSD will allow `ADCNT` to consist of either `EM` or `RUID` or both:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="EM" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="RUID" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element name="ADCNT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="RUID"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="EM"/>
          <xs:element ref="RUID" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

---

**Update:** I've changed the type of `RUID` to be complex per OP's request, but the principle remains the same:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="RUIDType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="username" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="ADCNT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="RUID" type="RUIDType"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="EM" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="RUID" type="RUIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: When I am adding complex type withing the element then I am getting the error but with this simple XS:String it's working. So, can you help me with the complex type.

Comment: Answer updated to change type of `RUID` to be complex, but note that the principle remains independent of the type of `RUID` or `EM`.